# Eclipse 4 product migration from Oxygen to Eclipse 2020-06 : ClassNotFoundException

Tags: osgi, eclipse-rcp, apache-felix

I migrate an Eclipse 4 product from Oxygen to Eclipse 2020-06.
I've got a ClassNotFoundException when some plugin try to load classes using reflection. All is well in the Oxygen version of the product.

By example with cxf, the  org.apache.cxf.cxf-core, try to load the org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter class.

This class is in the org.objectweb.asm bundle.

This problem of ClassNotFoundException is not specific to the org.apache.cxf.cxf-core bundle. I've got a similar problem with other bundle.

I compare the class loading between the Oxygen version and the Eclipse 2020-06 version without finding the issue.

The two same ClassLoader are used in the both versions :

- org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.ContextFinder
- org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader

The version of the JDK is the same for the two products : JDK8.

Is somebody have got a similar issue with class loading?

Comment: org.apache.felix.scr replaced org.eclipse.equinox.ds starting from 4.10 (2018-12). Have you updated the product start levels to start org.apache.felix.scr?

Comment: Thanks for comments. Yes we update the product from ds to scr. We just find the solution : bad plugin version. I update the question to mark it at solved.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :
The problem was due to a version incompatibility between cxf plugins and asm plugins. We fixed the problem by updating the version of cxf in our target platform.